# Order of onPreferenceChange invocation when 2 classes implement OnPreferenceChangeListener

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, preferenceactivity

I'm creating a class which `extends PreferenceActivity implements OnPreferenceChangeListener`, and it's the one which is inflating the xml preference resouece.

I also got a service which is also implementing `OnPreferenceChangeListener` on the same default SharedPreference.

When a user changes a preference in the preference screen, is there an absolute order of `onPreferenceChange` invocation? Can I be sure that the first invocation be called from within the activity and only after that will it be called from the service? And what happens if I create another change listener from a different class?